# Replace Windows logon ui (gina) with a win32 application

Tags: login, windows, gina

Is this possible to replace windows xp logon ui (i mean gina) with a win32 application? I don't talk a about writing a dll and replace it with windows original gina dll, I mean a **proper interactive win32 application** like notepad.exe

Comment: Do you have a particular use case in mind? This seems very strange to try and launch a program... especially before the Explorer process has even been launched.

Comment: Also, as this doesn't relate to the administration of multiple computers it may be better off asked at SuperUser.com instead of ServerFault.  Check out the site FAQs for what is and is not on topic here.

Answer (score 3):

Many software vendors override the Logon UI to run programs such as Fingerprint or Facial Recognition scanning software.  So yes you can override the default Windows Login UI even up to Windows 7.

However, it is only available to perform login operations.  You won't have access to certain system resources like mapped drives.  So if the intent was to be able to do certain things you would be stuck.  Again, If you are trying to run a kiosk style environment you could perform an auto-login and then have the program automatically open once Windows has loaded.

Any particular reason you are trying to do this with XP? Its support from Microsoft runs out pretty soon.

Comment: Your answer is factually inaccurate.  It is possible to replace the logon application or UI.  Alternate Windows shells replace the UI with their own, and as a "security" exercise, you can replace the logon application with arbitrary code to bypass the logon protections in Windows.  Of course, trying to replace it with Notepad would result in an inability to pass credentials to actually log on, but the "XP logon screen" is just an executable like any other, and can be replaced with a renamed file or application if desired.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Yea, you're right I had a brain fart. Updating the answer for anyone who finds this.