# Can I open an application before a user logs in?

Tags: windows, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace Windows logon ui (gina) with a win32 application](https://serverfault.com/questions/413374/replace-windows-logon-ui-gina-with-a-win32-application)

I want to open an application before a user logs in to the system. Is it possible to customize the Windows 7 user login screen so that we can add some options to open some application like onscreen board, so that users can open that application and check it?

Comment: This is more of a dev question than a sysadmin question as you're talking about serious code. It's (realively) trivial to write a service that runs in the background when no-one's logged in, but if you want an interactive program that runs at the login screen then what user context do you think it should run in? And how would users interact with that application once they've logged in and can't interact with that session any more? Does your app need to use network resources? Then whom does it log into those as? How will you secure it? This is far from a trivial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're truly asking, "can users run an interactive program without being logged into Windows" then the answer is "No."

But if you mean, "Can users run an interactive program without having to know or enter their Windows credentials" then the answer is yes:  you simply set up an auto-login process, and as soon as the PC boots, the user is ready to run an interactive session.  You can set particular programs up to autorun, so that the user doesn't even need to launch them.